# Any list view does not appear on Intranet when connecting via VPN

Tags: list, web-part, vpn

We have a staff intranet built on SharePoint 2013. When connecting through Cisco WebVPN on mobile devices (iOS or Android) our intranet loads successfully, however the webparts (standard Out of the box list view webparts) are not loading. This problem is not happening on desktop computers. Is this just something that is not supported by the latest versions of Cisco ASA? I read that an August 2015 update supports 2013, but see nothing about mobile devices. Any insights?

Comment: seems like the VPN is blocking some necessary ports--just a hunch.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the mobile page how it looks? It will help us to know the problem with SharePoint or VPN.